# Details of a proof for a theorem about Hilbert symbol

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Kato's *Number Theory 1: Fermat's Dream* writes:

> PROPOSITION 2.4. Let $v$ be a prime number or $\infty$. For $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ we have the following:
>   (1) $(a,b)_v = (b,a)_v$.
>   (2) $(a,bc)_v = (a,b)_v(a,c)_v$
>   (3) $(a,-a)_v = 1$. If $a\neq 1$, then $(a,1-a)_v = 1$.
>   ...

and

> THEOREM 2.5. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$. Then $(a,b)_v$ is equal to $1$ except for a finite number of $v$, and we have $$\prod_v (a,b)_v = 1$$ where $v$ runs through all the prime numbers and $\infty$.

In the second part of the proof of this theorem, this book says that in order to show that the product is $1$ it suffices to show it in the following cases (i)-(iii) since we have to prove it only for each prime factor of $a$ and $b$ and for $-1$ thanks to Prop. 2.4(1), (2) and (3).

(i) $a$ and $b$ are two distinct odd prime numbers.
(ii) $a$ is an odd prime number, and $b = -1$ or $2$.
(iii) $a=-1$, and $b=-1$ or $2$.

---

My question is, how can the Prop 2.4(1)-(3) be applied to reduce the proof to cases (i)-(iii)?

From 2.4(2) I know that we may consider the factor of $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$, but why is it prime? If we take $a = \frac{c}{d}\in\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ where $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$, then we can consider the prime factor of $c$, but what about $\frac{1}{d}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By multiplicativity, and the fact that $(1,b)_v = 1$, for any $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}^\times$ you get
$$(a^{-1},b)_v = (a,b)^{-1}_v = (a,b)_v,$$
which means that the product formula may be checked for the numerator and denominator separately:
$$(\frac{c}{d}, b)_v = (c, b)_v\cdot (d, b)_v.$$